# Mac ports Mysql install

Tags: python, mysql, django, macports

I completed my install on Leopard with Mac Ports. I also installed Mysqld via Mac Ports for use with python. I set the password for mysql on mysql start. Everything seemed to be fine except when I invoke mysql-start from the command line now I get this: mysql-start
*****Password:
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS! 
demetrius-fords-macbook-pro-17:~ demet8$

I also get a system que stating:Do you want mysqld to accepting incoming notifications.....

So I kinda think I am activating mysqld, not the actual mysql command interpreter. I can use mysql-stop with no problem to shut the server down. Lastly in the Python interpreter when I run:  ***import MySQLdb*** I get this:

/**opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py:34: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  from sets import ImmutableSet**

I don't think this affects mysqld @ all. I don't have the mysql default socket in my path via bash_login. Do I need to do that? thank you....

Comment: Try serverfault. Not any programming problem here.

Comment: Wow, you actually managed to install MySQLdb on Leopard? Lucky you.. Spent hours on it. In the end, gave up and used mysql connector/python (which worked immediately..)

Comment: Jani the install was pretty straightforward. The only problem I had was I thought was the correct path being set but from what I could tell the path was automatically set during the install. I connected with mysql5 like Mark suggested & it worked no problem. I couldn't find that alternate command anywhere on google last night...maybe I was just tired! thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command for the client is normally mysql (see [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting-disconnecting.html)) However in macports they have appended the major version number so try mysql5

The python error is only a depreciation so can be ignored

Comment: Mark it worked! I feel really stupid.....Thanks man. I goggled for hours trying to see if there was an alternate connect command to mysql via mac ports but I wasn't successful. Thank you again.